# while loop not executing

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I made a while loop inside a program and the program reaches the while loop, but it doesn't execute. I feel like there's a really tiny error that I'm missing since I've been looking at the code for so long.

```
  int strbuf = 100;
  char string[strbuf];
  char *exit = "exit";
  while(!strcmp(string, exit)){
      printf("Enter a word to search. Enter exit to quit");
      scanf("%s", string);
      state = present(fIndex, string);
      if(state){
        printf("The word %s was found on line %d", string, state);
    }
}
```

EDIT: the input is from the keyboard. 
EDIT EDIT: NEW CODE (same problem)

```
int strbuf = 100;
char string[strbuf];
char *exit = "exit";

printf("Enter a word to search. Enter exit to quit\n");
scanf("%s", string);
    while(!strcmp(string, exit)){
    state = present(fIndex, string);
    if(state){
        printf("The word %s was found on line %d", string, state);
    }
    else printf("The word %s was not found", string);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you suppose to take the input before the while loop once ? `string` has garbage initially on the initial loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the man page for `strcmp`:

> The  strcmp()  function compares the two strings s1 and s2.  It
>   returns
>          an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if  s1  is  found,
>          respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

If you have a match, `strcmp` will return 0, and if the two strings *don't* match it'll return a non-zero value.

Therefore `while(!strcmp(string, exit))` is really saying, *while the strings match*, continue to loop.

`string` is also uninitialized and contains junk, causing undefined behaviour. Either initialise it first or or use a `do..while` loop if your loop must execute *at least once*.

Comment: He is accounting for that. The condition is `!strcmp(string, exit)`.

Comment: A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.  He wants to run the loop as long as it isn't the case that the strings are equal.  while(strcmp(string, exit))  will run until the strings are equal.

Comment: @paxdiablo: He has `while(!strcmp(string, exit))`, it should be `while(strcmp(string, exit))` or `while(strcmp(string, exit) != 0`), did I misread something else? He wants to remain inside the loop until the user enters `"exit"`. Or is the point you're trying to make that he should be taking input before the loop?

Comment: @paxdiablo: No worries, you had me for a sec. Haven't eaten breakfast and it's almost 2pm so I assumed I stuffed up.

Comment: @tnecniv: He's checking if the strings match, and if they do to keep looping. That condition will cause the loop to terminate when the two strings *don't match*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it *is* executing. The *body* of the `while` loop may not be executing but that's because  what you're doing is undefined behaviour, using `string` before it's initialised to anything useful.

A simple fix is to change:

```
char string[strbuf];
```

into:

```
char string[strbuf] = {'\0'};
```

And, for the sake of readability, you should expand your comparisons unless they truly *are* boolean values,(and, since you're hard-coding "exit" in a few places, I'm not sure why you'd have it as a variable):

```
while (strcmp (string, "exit") != 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting input for `string` before comparing it with `exit`. Put a:

```
printf("Enter a word to search. Enter exit to quit");
scanf("%s", string);
```

before your while loop.

Comment: eh?? Is there something sarcastic am not getting here??

Comment: DRY = "Don't repeat yourself" - there's no need to input before the loop when you can just set the string to something other than "exit". The fact that I said it five times was _itself_ a form of meta-humour, which has now been rendered useless by the fact I had to explain it :-) That's okay, my wife often doesn't understand my strange brand of humour either. Think yourself fortunate you don't have to put up with it every day.

Comment: Well, thanks for your explanation. BTW, your last 2 lines cracked me up even though you had to explain the main joke ;)  URAWESOME ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the while loop is not being executed, it means `!strcmp(string, exit)` is false

which means `strcmp(string, exit)` must be tru (non 0)

strcmp returns 0 on a match, so `string` is no the same as `exit`

The reason for this? You never put a value in string.  Suggest changing it to a "do while" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, *exit()* is a standard C function (see stdlib.h).  Something like *strExit* may better suit your aims.